# Get form Id from OnSuccess or OnFailure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with multiple `Ajax.Beginform`.I disable submit button by `onClick` function, and I want to enable it back upon `OnSuccess` or `OnFailure` .The problem is that, I have same `OnSuccess` and `OnFailure` functions for all forms.So I need a way to figure out which form's OnSuccess or OnFailure function is invoked , in order to enable it's submit button.

Any suggestion how I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have multiple OnSuccess and OnFailures, each calling some function that re-enables the submit button. Could you just add a message to each of the OnSuccess and OnFailures and next to the re-enable function using Console.log("Message")? Then check the browser console (ex. use the firebug addon in firefox) to check the order of the messages to see when the re-enable function is being called?